# Update a table using id as part of the string to update

Tags: sql, sqlite, variables

I am trying to use the ID column for the value to set for example.

```
UPDATE my_items 
SET my_string = "mystrin-94990"  
WHERE id ="94990";
```

The issue here is dynamically appending the id for my_string column.

Ideally I'd like to update all records:

```
UPDATE my_items 
SET my_string = "mystrin-{ID}" 
WHERE my_string NOT LIKE "%{ID}%";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following may be of use (if the issue is understood correctly):-

```
UPDATE my_items SET my_string = my_string||id WHERE NOT instr(my_string,id);
```

or to cater for the issue mentioned below (i.e. to only check the trailing value for rerun-ability):-

```
UPDATE my_items SET my_string = my_string||id WHERE substr(my_string,length(my_string) - length(id) + 1,length(id)) NOT LIKE id;
```

The following demonstrates what the above does using the first (2nd has the same results):-

```
/* Clean up just in case */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_items;
/* Create the table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, my_string);
/* load some initial data */
INSERT INTO my_items (my_string) VALUES ('ms00A'),('ms00B'),('ms00C');
INSERT INTO my_items VALUES (2000,'ms00D');
INSERT INTO my_items (my_string) VALUES ('ms00E'),('ms006F'),('ms007G');
/* show the data */
SELECT * FROM my_items;
/* initial update */
UPDATE my_items SET my_string = my_string||id WHERE NOT instr(my_string,id);
/* show the results */
SELECT * FROM my_items;
/* add some more data */
INSERT INTO my_items (my_string) VALUES ('ms00H'),('ms00I'),('ms00J');
/* update only those rows that have not been updated */
UPDATE my_items SET my_string = my_string||id WHERE NOT instr(my_string,id);
/* show the results */
SELECT * FROM my_items;
UPDATE my_items SET my_string = my_string||id WHERE NOT instr(my_string,id);
/* show the results */
SELECT * FROM my_items;
/* Clean up test environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_items;
```

The initial data (1st SELECT) :-

[image]

After the Update :-

[image]

After the update after some new rows have been added:-

[image]

- Note this is subject to issues if the my_string column originally contains the value of the id column
- why though? (rhetorical) you can always extract or utilise my_string||id without duplicate the stored id.

Answer (score 0):

see if this works

```
UPDATE my_items 
SET my_string = CONCAT(my_string, '-', ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_items 
    SET
        my_string = SUBSTRING('mystrin-94990', 1, CHARINDEX('-','mystrin-94990') - 1)
WHERE
    id = SUBSTRING('mystrin-94990', CHARINDEX('-','mystrin-94990') + 1,
                    CHARINDEX('-','mystrin-94990') - 1
                );
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**